# Pcre regex with lazy quantifier

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a PCRE compatible regex to capture `My-Test` & `12345` from this string:

```
"My-Test:abc,def,ghi,jkl:12345"
```

Here is what I have got so far:

```
/(?<=:)(.*)(?=:)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/xKgh7j/1
I need the other parts of the entire line. `My-Test` is before the first colon. `12345` will always come after second (or last) colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one `^([^:]+):[^:]+:(.*)$`

https://regex101.com/r/Ebkzjb/1